Unable to compress API requests after following Microsoft Compression documentations
Hope I can get some help on this one as I have been stuck for over a week.
I followed the directions from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/iis-compression/iis-compression-overview but when making a HTTP request I have yet to see Content-Encoded from any API request.
Any advice what I should consider or how I should go about to possibly debug this one? I really appreciate all point in direction. Will add a few images which i hope shows some insight what it looks like on my end.




Try to get started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-modules-features/troubleshooting-iis-compression-issues-in-iis6-iis7x

You can try to locate the problem through the following two points:

Enable IIS failed request tracking, check if only the content-encoding header is not displayed in the browser. In the log you can view detailed request information. And static compression won't work if a static file didn't get hit frequently. Simply refer to this thread.
Check the antivirus protection settings. Antivirus software with settings enabled will protect the http connection (depending on the specific program), decompress the response to check it, and then dynamically rewrite the response headers.

